# connected to remote server ssh and cloning from GIT

Tags: git, ssh, clone

My question is very simple.

I am connected with ssh to my remote server.
I would like to make a git clone using ssh key in my remote server...
Each time

> Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

I have generated my ssh in my remote server private and public.
I have add my public key in gitlab.

But maybe I have forgot a step.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: Can you verify the ssh connection? `ssh -T user@server`

Comment: ssh: connect to host xxxx port 22: Connection refused

Comment: You don’t have permission. Have you provided the server with your public key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure you have your key in your remote server, and it has the proper permissions (600 or 400 will do). Just:

```
ssh-add route/to/your/key
```

and you should be able to clone properly.

**NOTE**: If your SSH agent is not running, start it with:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

Comment: I see my keys in my .ssh/ folder they are in and I have checked they are the one I have activated in gitlab.

Comment: eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" gives me 
Agent pid 405471

Comment: e.g, if the key is called `.ssh/id_rsa` just run `ssh-add .ssh/id_rsa` and try to clone.